# Combine Columns with same name in the same dataset in R

Tags: r

For example:
I have one df

df

| A | B | C | D | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
| 3 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 4 |

I would like to have this:

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| 3 | 4 | 4 | 4 |
| NA | NA | 5 | NA |
| NA | NA | 4 | NA |

Answer (score 1):

A base R option:

```r
l <- split.default(df, names(df)) |>
  lapply(\(x) unname(unlist(x)))
data.frame(sapply(l, "length<-", max(lengths(l))))

#   A  B C  D
#1  1  2 3  4
#2  3  4 4  4
#3 NA NA 5 NA
#4 NA NA 4 NA
```

Answer (score 1):

You might have done something wrong beforehand to get into this position so if you can try to fix issues upstream. Otherwise:

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(A = c(1,3), B = c(2,4), C = c(3, 4), D = c(4, 4), C = c(5, 4), .name_repair = "minimal")
df
#> # A tibble: 2 × 5
#>       A     B     C     D     C
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1     2     3     4     5
#> 2     3     4     4     4     4

dupe_names <- duplicated(names(df))
bind_rows(df[!dupe_names], df[dupe_names])
#> # A tibble: 4 × 4
#>       A     B     C     D
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1     2     3     4
#> 2     3     4     4     4
#> 3    NA    NA     5    NA
#> 4    NA    NA     4    NA
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `cbind.na`

```
out <- do.call(qpcR:::cbind.na, lapply(split.default(df, sub("\\.\\d+", "",
     names(df))), unlist))
row.names(out) <- NULL
```

-output

```
> out
      A  B C  D
[1,]  1  2 3  4
[2,]  3  4 4  4
[3,] NA NA 5 NA
[4,] NA NA 4 NA
```